# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' on Fedora

Tags: python, linux, fedora

I'm having this problem when i try to import numpy or any other modules of python on PyCharm or Visual Studio Code.

here's some things that i tried:

When i try to import direct via Python CLI the import works perfectly without any changes but when i use Visual Studio Code or Pycharm this problem happens even using their CLI, i tried the flatpak and distribution version of Pycharm and the problem continues.

I tried to change python interpreter of VSC using "commmand palette Python: Select interpreter" and the problem still happening

I installed Fedora workstation 37 on a VM only installing Pip, Numpy, VSC Flatpak via FlatHub and IntelliCode extension and the problem continues

Can someone help me?

**EDIT: I find the problem, the reason why i was having this problem is because the VSC Flatpak isn't well integrated with the system therefore not able to acess SDKs of my host system.
To anyone having similar problem you can see how to solve [here](https://github.com/flathub/com.visualstudio.code/blob/master/flatpak-warning.txt).**

Comment: _I tried to change python interpreter of VSC using "commmand palette Python: Select interpreter" and the problem still happening_ Which **specific** interpreter did you choose?  And are the desired modules installed **for that interpreter**?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add that part, yes, the numpy and all modules are installed via pip and works on CLI, my python version is 3.10.6 and i used this in:

/bin/python
/sbin/python

and like i said, they work when i use them using terminal emulator, but not on a IDE

Comment: Then your IDEs must be using other versions of Python that are installed on your computer.  Run this code in each IDE to see what interpreter they are using: `import sys; print(sys.executable)`

Comment: You're right, they are using different versions of python (Terminal Emulator uses 3.11.1 and VSC 3.10.6) but somehow the same directory, i don't know why this is happens, how can i change?

Comment: Change the IDEs to use `/bin/python`.